# Child component rerendered on every state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Live on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-pare-m595l?file=/src/App.js:298-306)

I have a simple example

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {useState} from "react";
const Child=({text,idx})=>{
  console.log(`Child - ${idx} rendered`);
  return <li>{text}</li>
}
const ShouldNotRender=()=>{
  console.log("Should not render")
  return <p>Should not render</p>
}
export default function App() {
  const [items,setItems]=useState([]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e)=>{
          setItems([...items,parseInt(Math.random()*500,10)]);
      }}>Add list</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item,idx)=>{
            return <Child text={item} key={idx} idx={idx}/>
        })}
      </ul>
      <ShouldNotRender/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see, whenever we add an item to the list, then `ShouldNotRender` is also rerendering. `ShouldNotRender` is not dependent on any of the states, then it should not rerender. It is a static and heavy component`(canvas)`.

I thought of splitting the component into two other components, one is static and the other is dynamic. Well, it worked fine but i don't understand that why react rerender `ShouldNotRender` component.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstand how state updates work.

Comment: The execution of the `render()` function will also cause `ShouldNotRender` to execute, so you can use `useMemo()` or `React.Memo` to prevent repeated rendering of the component

Comment: Thanks, now i understand why we should use `useMemo`

Comment: @Rahul - are you encountering performance issues? If not, don't memoize anything. Are you encountering logical issues? If so, and memo-izing it fixes them, it's because you're doing something else wrong and you should fix that first. React is very fast out of the box and you should only mess with perf optimizations, like memoizing stuff, when you need to. Don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

```
const ShouldNotRender = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("Should not render");
  return <p>Should not render</p>;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent re-rendering, you can memoize the component.

```
export default function App() {
  const [items,setItems]=useState([]);
  const memoizedShouldNotRender = useMemo(() => <ShouldNotRender/>, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e)=>{
          setItems([...items,parseInt(Math.random()*500,10)]);
      }}>Add list</button>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item,idx)=>{
            return <Child text={item} key={idx} idx={idx}/>
        })}
      </ul>
      {memoizedShouldNotRender}
    </div>
  );
}
```

See documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: This is an odd usage of `useMemo` - definitely not wrong, but odd. It's preferable to use `React.memo`, and moreover, you shouldn't do anything unless you specifically encounter performance issues and have no other way of fixing them.

Comment: It's important to note that memoisation shouldn't be relied on for application logic. ie. you should always assume that a component will rerender, even if you have memoised it.